# What horror movie feature a rock concert on an airplane?

Tags: identify-this-movie

In the late 90's early 2000's I caught part of this movie on at like 3AM on I think USA but could have been AMC.  It is a movie about the first full scale rock concert on a plane, then people start dying left and right.  I don't remember any actors.  Based on the amount of blood and death I would definitely say this was an R rated film.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's [Turbulence 3: Heavy Metal](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0251448/) (2001). The movie is rated R for violence. Synopsis:

> Terrorists hijack an airplane that is broadcasting a rock concert live
>   on the Internet.

Comment: Not a horror movie though. More like the typical hijack action movie plus some heavy metal and some horrible stereotypes.